# Merge two dataframes by nearest but lower index

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes `df_aux` and `df_sgl`. The latter is indexed every 100 milliseconds.

```
df_aux.head()
Out[57]: 
                              0
Time                           
2017-09-05 09:30:00.570     0.0
2017-09-05 09:30:05.234   400.0
2017-09-05 09:30:05.235   200.0
2017-09-05 09:30:05.256   100.0
2017-09-05 09:30:20.585  1795.0

df_sgl.head()
Out[58]: 
                         OBV
Time                        
2017-09-05 09:30:00.100  NaN
2017-09-05 09:30:00.200  NaN
2017-09-05 09:30:00.300  NaN
2017-09-05 09:30:00.400  NaN
2017-09-05 09:30:00.500  NaN
```

I want to perform a right join on the index such that the `df_sgl` prevails and each value of `df_aux` is assigned to the closest but higher instant. For example, the first value being replaced will be

```
2017-09-05 09:30:00.600  0.0
```

and the second one will be

```
2017-09-05 09:30:05.300  400.0
```

I tried to use `merge_asof` but the values were not preserved.

Thanks.

---

Found the following solution but I'm still open for an easier one.

```
df_aux['groupid'] = df_sgl.index[[ df_sgl.index.searchsorted(t) for t in df_aux.index ]]
df_aux = df_aux.groupby(by=['groupid']).sum()
df_sgl.merge(df_aux, how = 'left', left_index = True, right_index = True)
```